# execute google image search several times in a page

Tags: javascript, html, google-search-api

I want to write a web page which can generate images get from google search dynamically.
The search terms for these images are different, so I need to execute google search several times, while I found it is very hard.
I try these code modified from the source code google provided, but it could only execute the search one time:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <title>Google Search API Sample</title>
 <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('search', '1');

  var imageSearch;
    var keyword="sexy";

  function searchComplete() {


    // Check that we got results
    if (imageSearch.results && imageSearch.results.length > 0) {

      // Grab our content div, clear it.
      var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
      contentDiv.innerHTML = '';


      var results = imageSearch.results;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        // For each result image to the screen
        var result = results[i];
        var imgContainer = document.createElement('div');


        var newImg = document.createElement('img');

        // There is also a result.url property which has the escaped version
        newImg.src=result.tbUrl;

        imgContainer.appendChild(newImg);

        // Put our title + image in the content
        contentDiv.appendChild(imgContainer);
      }

      //clear search 
      imageSearch.clearResults();

    }
  }

  function OnLoad() {

    // Create an Image Search instance.
    imageSearch = new google.search.ImageSearch();

    // Set searchComplete as the callback function when a search is 
    // complete.  The imageSearch object will have results in it.
    imageSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete, null);

    imageSearch.execute(keyword);
  }


  function hi(){
      keyword="usa";
      alert('hi');
       google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
      imageSearch.execute(keyword);
  }  


 google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

</script>

 </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
   <button value="hi" onClick="hi">hi</button>
<div id="content">Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The program can only execute the search in OnLoad method. Actually, I tried to call google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad) multiple times by put it into hi() function, but it didn't work.
Hope someone can help me to solve these problem..

Comment: Julian - did the below answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

change `<button value="hi" onClick="hi">hi</button>` to

`<button value="hi" onClick="hi()">hi</button>`

Answer (score 0):

The `hi` function doesn't make a lot of sense to me:

```
function hi(){
    keyword="usa";
    alert('hi');
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    imageSearch.execute(keyword);
}
```

Because the `onLoadCallbak` has *already* been set, and a search executed in `OnLoad`. This is called when the search library has loaded. Which only happens once, at some point after the page has loaded.

What you need to do in `hi` is the same thing you're doing in `OnLoad`:

```
// Create an Image Search instance.
imageSearch = new google.search.ImageSearch();

// set a DIFFERENT callback (if different handling require)
imageSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete, null);

// set "keyword" to what your next search should be for
imageSearch.execute(keyword);
```